# Overtaking Apple In App purchase in iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS app which has video contents to be watched inside app. I have website which does the same and Android which does the same as well. So, when I start developing for iOS, I implemented APIs to make payment which connect to my backend server which connects to Payment APIs to get payments (user will have to enter credit card though).

So my question is can I ask user to subscribe through website/Android app to see the content in iOS app (in any help article/through any alert message)?

Comment: A user can log in to their account in an iOS app to access content that they have already subscribed to on the web site, but the app cannot provide any way to purchase a subscription and this includes having a link in your app that opens the web site in Safari to let the user subscribe

Comment: There is more. Knowing that a link would cause my app to be rejected, once I just put a label stating "Subscribe on our website" and they rejected my app anyway. So you either don't say anything at all, or give them In-App purchases.